# Windows WCF client with internet proxy server showing error The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

Our team trying to create a windows application(c#) to call a WCF service using internet proxy server

Showing exception "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" while calling WCF service

Please give suggestion to solve this problem/any other alternative solution

```
//Code for creating proxy
public static DevicesServiceClient CreateProxy()
{
  var proxy = new DevicesServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IDevicesService");

  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
  binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
  binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
  binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
  binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", "192.168.0.20","808"));
  proxy.Endpoint.Binding = binding;

  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
}
```

Server stack trace:

> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at DevicesService.IDevicesService.CheckNetworkConnection(String ipAddress)

My client side code in app.config
[image]

My server side code in web.config
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to call wcf service from windows client application using proxy server

```
            {
              var proxy = new DevicesServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IDevicesService");
              BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding("BasicHttpBinding_IDevicesService");
              var proxySettings = ApplicationDetails.CheckProxySettings();

                Uri domainAddress;
                var strtemp = new string[] { };
                //WebProxy webproxy = new WebProxy();
                var networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
                if (proxySettings.ProxyServerType == "http")
                {
                    domainAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxySettings.ProxyServerAddress, proxySettings.ProxyServerPort));
                }
                else if (proxySettings.ProxyServerType == "https")
                {
                    domainAddress = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}:{1}", proxySettings.ProxyServerAddress, proxySettings.ProxyServerPort));
                }
                else
                {
                    domainAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxySettings.ProxyServerAddress, proxySettings.ProxyServerPort));
                }
                //
                WebProxy webproxy = new WebProxy(domainAddress.ToString(), true, strtemp);
                //

                //networkCredentials.Domain = domainAddress.ToString();
                if (proxySettings.ProxyAuthentication == "1")
                {
                    networkCredentials.UserName = proxySettings.Username;
                    networkCredentials.Password = proxySettings.Password;
                }
                webproxy.Credentials = networkCredentials;
                webproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webproxy;
                binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
                proxy.Endpoint.Binding = binding;

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen this exception before but I already had big problems to make proxy work this way. I don't know why but setting proxy address and use default proxy to false in BasicHttpBinding never worked for me. I always had to use default web proxy and set the URL there or create whole new custom binding and set proxy URL in http transport binding element.

Comment: Please give code/reference for solving this problem that you already mentioned in your answer "use default web proxy and set the URL there or create whole new custom binding and set proxy URL in http transport binding element."

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the headers returned by your proxy server. It looks like malformed/non standard headers cause this exception.

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t302174-why-do-i-get-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is something of a catch-all exception and has limited utility as a result. Malformed headers, hitting the wrong port (that returns a different formatted response), and content-length in the response can all be causes for the exception. If it's a header issue, you can tell the client to ignore unsafe headers (if it's a trusted source).

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
        </settings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Not a header issue, then. My next suspect would be content length. Check the binding configurations on both the server and client for MaxXXXMessageSize (XXX = Received or Sent) and bump them.

Comment: Now Client side app.config & Server side web.config code showing in the question

Comment: Now i increased maxReceivedMessageSize & maxBufferSize attributes values in the client side,showing same error

Comment: Can you do the same on the server side? That's where I ran into the problem when it hit me...

Comment: <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

Answer (score 2):

Try to diagnose this one step at a time.

1. Change the servicebehavior to add `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true"/>` Then change the proxy setting in IE and browse to the service url and see if you can get the WSDL page.
2. Do the above with [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and see if there are any errors. If WSDL is available generate proxy and call the operation to check for errors.
3. Enable WCF tracing as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). The tracelogs are very detailed and I have diagnosed many WCF issues using this technique.
4. Finally try network tracing using [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a network trafic analyser to get more informations about what is sent and received by your client and server? This could help you solving the issue, or perhaps at least identifying the root cause.